# Can Azure Search integrate seamlessly with Azure DocumentDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

According to the [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-get-started/), for Azure search to work, the data needs to be uploaded to the search service. If i have a No-SQL database in Azure as DocumentDB, can the search service be configured to access the data directly from database, rather than uploading the data to the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not comment below the current thread, so I will add a new reply.

I am a Program Manager with Azure Search and I can confirm Daron's comments about this being a top request.  There is also a fair amount of voting for it from our UserVoice page (http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328680-auto-indexing-of-docdb).  As a result, we have been investigating tighter integration of these technologies.

Comment: Liam, does documentDb support full text search?

Comment: Abhay, I am not on the DocumentDB team so I can not comment officially, but I believe the answer is no.  I will ping Ryan CrawCour from this team to respond to this officially.

Comment: DocumentDB does not support full text search today. We recommend customers use Azure Search for doing this, and more.

Comment: As of recent, you can now integrate Azure Search and DocumentDB easily with indexers! It's pretty amazing... check out: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/documentdb-search-indexer/

Answer (score 0):

DocumentDB has POST triggers. You might be able to use it for an integration.

From my understanding a built-in integration is one of the top requests in the Azure Search and DocDB community. We had a lot of discussions around this with DocDB / Azure Search insiders and I remember a lot of people asking for it.

Comment: "*This is one of the top requests*" - not sure where you gleaned that info. And it's irrelevant. Also, "Not yet" implies that integrated search is on the roadmap (and there's no such announcement of that).

Comment: These are just my feelings. You are right. I don't have concrete sources that I can share. I will edit my post to reflect the fact that my answer is based on my personal assumptions and understanding of the community around DocDB and Azure Search users/developers.

Comment: You cannot use POST triggers today directly as you cannot call to external systems using triggers from DocumentDB. You could write the search info to a separate document using a POST trigger, and use a separate process to write these documents to Search if you like.